# Debug: find the middle word(s) in a list of words

Tags: python

Purpose: find the middle word(s) in a list of words

Attempt:

```
words = ['Baa', 'Baa', 'black', 'sheep', 'have', 'you', 'any', 'wool']
s=words.split('')
length = len(words)
 if length % 2 == 1:
  print s(length/2)
 else:
  print s((length/2) + ((length/2) +1))
```

---

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<web session>", line 2, in <module> 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 2):

`.split()` is a method used for a string, to break it into an array.  Your words are already in an array and do not need to be split.

Read the error message you are receiving; it will usually give you a clue what's going on.